# Image load from network when it appeare on screen flutter

Tags: flutter

> load image when it appears on a screen. do not load when the image container does not on display area does not load an image from the network.

Comment: You question is a bit confusing.
https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/painting/NetworkImage-class.html
https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/cached_network_image
https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/images/network-image

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question is slightly confusing, but I will interpret it as such that you want to load the image only when it is on the screen in flutter. And not to load when it is not on the screen. This is usually called lazy-loading.

In flutter, this can be implemented using multiple libraries:

**1.**

Add `lazy_load_scrollview` dependency to your `pubspec.yaml`:

```
dependencies:
  lazy_load_scrollview: 0.0.1
```

In your Dart code, `import package:lazy_load_scrollview/lazy_load_scrollview.dart` Then you can wrap your `ListView` or `GridView` with the `LazyLoadScrollView`. Make sure you add an `endOfPageListener` which will receive the call when the bottom of the list has been reached.

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: LazyLoadScrollView(
        endOfPageListener: () => loadMore(),
        child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: data.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, position) {
            return Text("Position $position");
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
}
```

This was developed by [QuirijnGB](https://github.com/QuirijnGB/lazy-load-scrollview), and the library is available [here](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/lazy_load_scrollview).

**2**

On the other hand, you can use`flutter_pagewise`, which also implements this by default. [Flutter Pagewise](https://github.com/AbdulRahmanAlHamali/flutter_pagewise) supports `ListView`, `GridView`, `SliverListView` and `SliverGridView`, and I think GridView might be useful for your images.

For this,

Add this into your dependency

```
dependencies:
    flutter_pagewise:
```

Then import it to your page,

```
import 'package:flutter_pagewise/flutter_pagewise.dart';
```

And then your listview would work like this:

```
PagewiseListView(
  pageSize: 10,
  padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
  itemBuilder: (context, entry, index) {
    // return a widget that displays the entry's data
  },
  pageFuture: (pageIndex) {
    // return a Future that resolves to a list containing the page's data
  }
);
```

I hope that helps!